# Как определить браузер пользователя?

Tags: javascript, jquery

$.browser  не работает  в последних версиях

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp или https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замена `$.browser`, там есть пример в файле `demo.html`
https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.browser/